# Add an instance declaration mistake in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell. This is the code which I made:

```
transition_world world = case world of
   (Head,(x,y)):cs-> (Tail,(x,y)): transition_world cs
   (Tail,(x,y)):cs -> (Conductor, (x,y)): transition_world cs
   (Empty, (x,y)):cs -> (Empty, (x,y)): transition_world cs 
   (Conductor, (x,y)):cs
     | element_occurrence Head == 1 || element_occurrence Head == 2
                  -> (Head, (x,y)): transition_world cs
     | otherwise  -> (Conductor, (x,y)): transition_world cs
   [] -> []
```

While trying to compile, GHCi gives me this error:

```
Sources\Transitions\For_List_2D.hs:23:33:
No instance for (Eq (List_2D Cell -> Data.Integer_Subtypes.Nat))
  arising from a use of `=='
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Eq (List_2D Cell -> Data.Integer_Subtypes.Nat))
In the first argument of `(||)', namely
  `element_occurrence Head == 1'
In the expression:
  element_occurrence Head == 1 || element_occurrence Head == 2
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               a case alternative:
  element_occurrence Head == 1 || element_occurrence Head == 2

Sources\Transitions\For_List_2D.hs:23:36:
No instance for (Num (List_2D Cell -> Data.Integer_Subtypes.Nat))
  arising from the literal `1'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Num (List_2D Cell -> Data.Integer_Subtypes.Nat))
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `1'
In the first argument of `(||)', namely
  `element_occurrence Head == 1'
In the expression:
  element_occurrence Head == 1 || element_occurrence Head == 2
```

Can't understand what does it want from me... Where did I make a mistake? And how can I fix it?

Extra 1:

```
element_occurrence :: Eq e => e -> List_2D e -> Nat
element_occurrence element list = case list of
    (local_element, _): cs
       | local_element == element -> 1 + element_occurrence element cs
       | otherwise                ->     element_occurrence element cs
    [] -> 0
```

Extra 2:

```
local_elements :: Coord -> List_2D e -> List_2D e
local_elements (x, y) list = read_neighbours (x, y) 1 list
  where
    read_neighbours :: Coord -> Distance -> List_2D e -> List_2D e
    read_neighbours (x, y) dist list = case list of
        (element, (x_e, y_e)): cs
            |    abs (x_e - x) <= dist
            && abs (y_e - y) <= dist -> (element, (x_e, y_e)): read_neighbours (x, y) dist cs
            | otherwise              ->                        read_neighbours (x, y) dist cs
        [] -> []

local_elements_list :: Coord -> List_2D e -> [e]
local_elements_list (x, y) list = read_neighbours_list (x, y) 1 list
  where
    read_neighbours_list :: Coord -> Distance -> List_2D e -> [e]
    read_neighbours_list (x, y) dist list = case list of
        (element, (x_e, y_e)): cs
            |  abs (x_e - x) <= dist
            && abs (y_e - y) <= dist -> element: read_neighbours_list (x, y) dist cs
            |  otherwise             ->          read_neighbours_list (x, y) dist cs
        [] -> []

size :: List_2D e -> Nat
size list = case list of
   []    -> 0
   _: xs -> 1 + size xs
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Cloud you please add the code for `element_occurrence`? Anyway, the error tells you that ghc don't know how to compare a value of type `List_2D Cell -> Data.Integer_Subtypes.Nat` (which is a function) to 1. The expression `element_occurrence Head` is probably missing an argument.

Comment: Just added the extra code

Comment: I think I understood what I miss. I also have to specify that element_occurence should look for 8 adjacent cells, not the whole picture. I still can't understand how I specify it. I guess I spent so much time staring at code that I can't notice obvious thing. I added some extra bits of code. Hope it will help.

Comment: @user3493630 I think you are [from reddit](http://www.reddit.com/user/CanberraStudent).  In general we don't like doing other people's homework here, either.  Maybe try #haskell on IRC (Freenode), and let them know it is homework up front.  It'll also be more interactive.

Answer (score 3):

"Add an instance declaration for..." is one of GHC's most misleading error messages. Generally you should ignore that advice.

If the type it wants an instance for has a `->` in it, this basically shows you're trying to do something with a function that's only possible with the *result*, i.e. you've forgotten to apply the function to all its arguments. Evidently, `element_occurence` has a type something like `Item -> List_2D Cell -> Nat`, but you have only `element_occurrence Head` in your code, which is a *partially applied function*, it still has type `List_2D Cell -> Nat`. By applying that to a `List_2D Cell`, you'll get a `Nat` which you can then compare to a number literal.

Comment: I think I understood what I miss. I also have to specify that element_occurence should look for 8 adjacent cells, not the whole picture. I still can't understand how I specify it. I guess I spent so much time staring at code that I can't notice obvious thing. I added some extra bits of code. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined element_occurence as a function of 2 arguments:

```
element_occurrence :: Eq e => e -> List_2D e -> Nat
element_occurrence element list = -- more stuff
```

You've called element_occurence with only one argument:

```
transition_world world = case world of
{- other cases -}
(Conductor, (x,y)):cs
  | element_occurrence Head == 1 || element_occurrence Head == 2 -> -- stuff
```

But, that gives you a value of type "List_2D Cell -> Nat", a function type, which you try to test equality against "1" and "2".

What you need to do is provide both arguments to element_occurence.

GHC is way too subservient here, and assume you **really** meant to only call with one argument.  (==) has type "Eq a => a -> a -> Bool", so the call to (==) will be okay if you provided an instance "Eq (List_2D Cell -> Nat)", but it can't find that instance.  So, it prints the first error message.

GHC figures, you are *awesome* so you'll fix that error *right away*, and proceeds under the assumption that it is fixed.  But now it sees "1" and "2" in a place where it is expecting a "List_2D Cell -> Nat", the other side of (==).  Now, numeric literals are overloaded to have type "Num a => a", so that *could* be a "List_2D Cell -> Nat" if you provide an instance "Num (List_2D Cell -> Nat)".  It can't find that instance, and so it spits out the second error message.